# Styling HTML Table in Email Body

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, html-table, inline

I have built an HTML table in the body of an email, I built the table like this:

```
<table><tr><td>Field 1</td><td>Value 1/<td></tr>
       <tr><td>Field 2</td><td>Value 2</td></tr>
```

I have tried to add in line styling like this:

```
<style>table,td{border: 1px solid black;}</style>
<table><tr><td>Field 1</td><td>Value 1/<td></tr>
       <tr><td>Field 2</td><td>Value 2</td></tr></table>
```

But it doesn't add borders to my table, I just need to add a border, pad the Fields to the right and change the color of the border on the table. The above inline style, from my thoughts should add a border and change the color. I am doing this in vb.net, so I don't belive I can make a Css class. That would be easiest of course. Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

I do this with templates for email... Type in userId and prss go button with a html coded email...

My body i put as a string..

```
myBody = <"html>"
myBody = myBody + "<body>"
myBody =.......
```

Etc etc... I would split each tag into a.new line...
Makes it easy to read for me...

I cant get code for an example (my son is sick and alseep on me).. Hope it helps.. Ill get me code for you later if you want?

Comment: Yeah I have it very similar to that.... I have my body built into a string variable and build the body by appending string.. My only issue is the lines for the table are not showing up

Answer (score 0):

this is the start of my email template
but i havent got a table inside it...

```
strEmail = "<HTML>"
strEmail &= "<BODY>"
strEmail &= "<SPAN style=""font-family: Arial; color:#000000; font-size: .75em;"">"
strEmail &= ("Hello " & UsersName & ",")
strEmail &= "<BR><BR>"
strEmail &= "Your password reset request has been actioned."
strEmail &= "<BR>"
```

hope this helps... when i get time il play around ... if you havent worked it out ill post something...

Comment: i thing it is better to use `StringBuilder.Append()` method to do this and assign the string builder to the mail body

Answer (score 0):

The way I format tables and cells in an email is very simple.. Include a `<style></style>` block and it shall take care of every thing:

```
<style>
  table,td   /* just to make a border on each cell as well as on the table itself*/
  { 
    border: 1px solid black;
  }
</style>

<table><tr><td>Field 1</td><td>Value 1/<td></tr>
       <tr><td>Field 2</td><td>Value 2</td></tr>
```

Comment: I edited my code above and am still getting nothing with the second snippet of code.... any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Look at this answer:
http://forums.asp.net/t/1576750.aspx?Email+a+Styled+HTML+Table

It works if you do the styling inside the html tags, like so:

```
<table width='600' border='0' align='center' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0'>
```

Of course, If you need to see the line you will use border='1'